# Running an angular project with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I've an angular project that I can run without issues with `ng serve`. But I have to use node.js to have access to a DB.

I've created a file server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './','index.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 4800;

app.listen(port, (req,res) => {
    console.log(`RUNNING on port ${port}`);
});
```

And this index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>AngNode</title>
      <base href="/">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
      <app-root></app-root>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the server.js file I got the `RUNNING on port 4800` but when I open the browser I got nothing but a blank page and no error. I tried to add a `Hello World` before the `<app-root></app-root>` and it's been displayed on the window but that's all.

I don't have any error on my console or on the browser so I don't know how to correct it.

Thank you

Comment: you can build your angular app and serve build output directory index file from your node.js rout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your angular application is not running under 4800 but under 4200 (by default) so although you are not getting js errors you are probably getting 404 in the request tab.

You need to setup a proxy in your angular application (for development see https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/) or, in case  you want to deliver the files from the express server, you need to compile the app, deploy the bundled version and configure your express to correctly deliver the files you need depending on the path.

Comment: So can I just change the port 4800 by 4200 ?

Comment: if you change to port 4200 you will see the app that is served by ng serve but you will not be able to reach your express application without setting up the proxy configuration

Comment: Ok, I tried to change this port to test but I still have a blank page is it normal ?

Comment: Maybe you are getting errors on your angular application

Comment: It may be because I run the angular project not on localhost:4200 but on 192.168.202.70:4200

Comment: I don't know about your specific network configuration or platform, but by default, if you just run in your computer ng serve you get an app running on http://localhost:4200/ (or http;//127.0.0.1:4200/) but you can check the angular console to see in which url it is running...

Comment: I'm running it on a server